# expandable list items changed after collapsing

Tags: android, imageview, expandablelistview

I create an expandable list and in each items I have an `imageview`. when User click on `imageview` its resource should be change to another resource. for example when `R.drawable.onalarm` is it, after user clicked it should change to `R.drawable.offalarm` . But after collapsing the group. the resource of imageview returns to its previous state. also i change the data of expandable list but it not working! this is my list Adapter:

```
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<GroupItem> items;
    public void setData(List<GroupItem> items) 
    {
            this.items = items; 
    }    
    @Override
    public View getRealChildView( final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ChildHolder holder;
        ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ChildHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            holder.alarm = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_imageview);
        } else {
            holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(item.title);
        holder.alarm.setImageResource(item.alarmid);
        holder.alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                if(iv.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
                        (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onalarm).getConstantState())) {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.offalarm);
                    items.get(groupPosition).items.get(childPosition).alarmid = R.drawable.offalarm;
                    setData(items);
                }
                else {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.onalarm);
                    items.get(groupPosition).items.get(childPosition).alarmid = R.drawable.onalarm;
                    setData(items);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

what should i do?
tnx

Comment: have you tried using notifyDatasetChanged() ?

Comment: @Bhargav no I didn't try that, now i used it and working fine. tnx. type your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using notifyDatasetChanged() right after you change the image

Answer (score 0):

you must set tag for ImageView and check it...
true for onalarm and false for offalarm....
try this:

```
   boolean clicked = new Boolean(false);
  iv.setTag(clicked);
public void onClick(View v) {



if( ((Boolean)iv.getTag())==false ){
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.onalarm);
iv.setTag(new Boolean(true));
}
else
 {
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.offalarm);
iv.setTag(new Boolean(false));
}
}
```